# Window object with Javascript in VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am new to Javascript and trying out this code from a book. It says the `window` object is to be displayed with a browser. I have Node.js installed. But when I run the code below (with F5), I get this message:

```
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught ReferenceError: alert is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
var age = 29;
var sayAge = () => alert(this.age);
alert(window.age);
sayAge();
window.sayAge();
```

How do I go about seeing what this code output is?

Comment: that code needs to be run in the browser, not in Node. `alert` and `window` aren't part of JS itself, they're provided by the browser environment.

Comment: (also, that's horrible code anyway - `this.age` will equal 29 when you call `sayAge()`, but only when done outside of "strict mode" (which you should always use). I advise you to learn JS from a better and more up-to-date resource.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `console.log()` instead. Alert is for a popup type alert in a browser.

`console.log()` can be used in either the browser or NodeJS

E.g. `console.log(age)`

It will either log to the NodeJS console that's running your application, or the browser console if you're using it in a browser environment

Comment: Thanks. I actually want to see how this "popup" looks like. I thought Node.js is to provide the runtime like a browser?

Comment: `I thought Node.js is to provide the runtime like a browser` it provides a runtime, but not like a browser. Node.js is intended for running server-side javascript, or command-line javascript.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that your code has no idea where that alert method is from.
In order to make use of that alert i use html. If u dont know how to code html i suggest u take a look because is very handy.
Follows an example from w3schools.com
I suggest u use Visual Studio Code if you are working on a project, or just edit from w3schools or a similar website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Button Text!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Alert!");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```